# Picture as list item not displayed in Chrome browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-lists, image

For some reason the picture in the `<li></li>` stopped being displayed by Chrome browser. It is displayed in Firefox and even IE. I did a cache refresh in Chrome Shift+F5, but it did not help.

The related code section is below.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.itse.co.za" title="For Consulting Services" target="_blank"><img src="images/adverts/itse-hori.jpg" width="280" height="158" alt="itse" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

What is going wrong? Is it my browser or my code?

Comment: Can you replicate this issue on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

I tested in Chrome and it worked, check the settings of your browser, or try the full url in the image.

```
<ul><li><a href="http://www.itse.co.za" title="For Consulting Services" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn.sejalivre.org/uploads/2011/08/firefox.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="itse" /></a></li></ul>
```